# stop view controller from reloading after another view controller is dismissed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 ViewControllers: `ControllerA` and `ControllerB`

On the `ControllerA` there are many tableViews and input boxes that the user might have filled out. From the `ControllerA` the user can click a button to launch `ControllerB` like so: (i am not using a NavigationController)

```
UIStoryboard *storyBorad = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: @"Main_iphone" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *secondController = [Storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ControllerB"];
[self presentViewController: secondController animated: YES completion: nil];
```

In the `ControllerB` the user can click the close button and the following code is exectured:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

The user is returned to the previous `ControllerA` but i see that `ControllerA` reloads all its data and everything in the text boxes is empty.

I read a lot of cases similar but don't understand how i go about solving this.

**Options i found:**

1. Save data somewhere before going to `ControllerB` and then when returning to `ControllerA` check for saved data and load it. How do i do this?? (seems tedious).
2. Find some way that the `ControllerA` does not get removed from memory and is there when the user returns from `ControllerB`. I would prefer this to keep things simple (i know the memory speech).

Any help?

Comment: please show some code from your viewcontroller A!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the data in fields, you need to push instead of presenting the VC modally.

Create a navigation controller and init with your VC and then present the VC like:

```
   UIStoryboard *storyBorad = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: @"Main_iphone" bundle:nil];
   UIViewController *secondController = [Storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ControllerB"];

   UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];

   [navController pushViewController:secondController animated:YES];
```

In this case, when you click on back button, you will be taken back to your previous VC and you won't loose any data!!!!

If you don't want o have back button, you can hide the navigation bar, and if you want to dismiss the `secondController`,you can simply call:

```
     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Also make sure you don't clear all the data in the fields when you move away from your VC!!!! (Make sure to check `viewDidDisappear/viewWillDisappear` if data is getting nil or not)

Comment: i do not think that presenting a viewcontroller modally is the problem. @s.d.: can you show some code from your ControllerA?

Comment: i don't have any code in A!!!! I just put some fields filled with data for testing!!!! and then i pushed to next VC and come back, the text is still there in the fields

Answer (score 0):

The view is the wrong place to store data you care about.  What's happening is that the view for controller A is being unloaded while B is presented.  If you want to be sure that user changes are preserved, you have to do it yourself.

A simple technique is to have an NSMutableDictionary in which you keep the data.  Fill the dictionary right before presenting B, and in viewWillAppear, populate your views from the dictionary.  If B was never presented, there's nothing to restore and the dictionary will be empty.  This means you don't need to test whether to restore; you can just enter that code path unconditionally.